Spotfire - Conditional Formatting - Color Scheme - Different Column Values
I have a cross table in Spotfire than I am trying to add a color scheme to but can't seem to figure out how to do it the way that I need it.
The image below isn't actual table obviously.

For this example, I am focusing on Measure 1. Each entity - facility has different targets, so Measure 1 for Facility A would be green if greater than or equal to 40, B to 50, C to 60. Any value less than the target value would be grey for that measure.
I can get the color scheme to work fine for each measure if the target for each facility is the same. I just can't figure out how to do it if each facility - entity has a different target.
Hopefully what I'm trying to do makes sense. If not, I'm happy to explain further.
